# Date incorrectly converts into required format (dd/mm/yy) in excel

Tags: excel, excel-dates

Hi I know lots of similar questions can be found here, but I am still facing this problem:
I have a table with one column called Dates with some values shown below:

12/2/2021
11/2/2021
10/2/2021
9/2/2021
8/2/2021
7/2/2021
6/2/2021
5/2/2021
4/2/2021
3/2/2021
2/2/2021
1/2/2021
31/01/21
30/01/21

When I try to convert it using Format cells either by selecting category as Date or adding custom category as dd/mm/yy, excel treat the dd/mm/YYYY values as mm/dd/yy.
So for example, instead of treating 1st row as 12 February, excel thinks of it as 2 December.

I also tried convert text to columns by going to DATA and setting it as DMY but it doesn't solve the problem.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Are you importing it from an external source?

Comment: I am doing an assessment where they have given an excel sheet with this weird dates. As a part of it, I have to set the dates into right format (dd/mm/yy).

Comment: Are the values text or numbers?

Comment: @EEM asked the key question - first check of those are actual dates (which are numbers in Excel) or text. Also check your date formatting options in Excel and for your OS.

If these are text dates rather than numerical and you they are formatted with two different rules (day/month and month/day), you're in a world of hurt and will need to fix them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
= DATE( YEAR(A1), DAY(A1), MONTH(A1) )
```

If the values have any `space` character, try this one:

```
= DATE( YEAR(TRIM(A1)), DAY(TRIM(A1)), MONTH(TRIM(A1)) )
```

Comment: It does convert the ones that has values that has (YYYY) like 12/2/2021 but doesn't convert for 31/01/21 (YY). But I think I can use if error function for that. Thanks a lot

Comment: Upsss, I missed those last two lines…

Comment: How those two lines are converted by your system?

Comment: I mean to say that, for the dates like 31/01/21 they are already in the correct format. The issues was with the ones like 12/2/2021. So what happened was for 12/2/2021 it converted it into 12 Feb 21 as I wanted but for 31/01/21 it shows as #value. So I used iferror function.  so my formula is now =IFERROR( DATE( YEAR(TRIM(A2)), DAY(TRIM(A2)), MONTH(TRIM(A2)) ),A2).

Comment: Forgot to mention something very important.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- All the dates were originally DMY
- Your windows regional settings short date format is MDY

You will need to convert to a proper date

- If the value is text, then it will be in DMY format and you can extract the sections and convert to a date
- If the value is numeric, then it has been converted improperly and you need to reverse the month and day part

Given those assumptions, the following formula should work.

I am using the `LET` and `FILTERXML` functions which are available in Excel Office 365 Windows versions.

If you don't have that version of Excel, you can still do this with formulas but it will be more complex.  Or you can use VBA.

```
=IFERROR(DATE(YEAR(A1),DAY(A1),MONTH(A1)),
  LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s"),
         DATE(INDEX(x,3)+IF(INDEX(x,3)<30,2000),INDEX(x,2),INDEX(x,1))))
```

[image]